# html5 multiple canvas wont overlap

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

New to HTML5 game development.

I am trying to overlap 2 canvases on each other. #canvasBG and #canvasJet. 
This should be working im not sure why it isn't.

my html

```
<button id="clearCanvasBtn" type="button">Clear Canvas</button>
<canvas id="canvasBg" width="800px" height="500px"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasJet" width="800px" height="500px"></canvas>
<div id="inner"></div>
```

my css

```
#canvasBg {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin: 100px auto 0px;
    display:block;
}

#canvasJet {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    margin: -500px auto 0px;
    display:block;
}
```

You can check it out right now here: http://dev.yeahnah.tv/gina/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `position: relative`:

```
#canvasBg, #canvasJet {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```